# Kotlin retrofit generic ClassCastException

Tags: android, json, kotlin, generics, retrofit

```
@POST("/Account/LogOn")
fun logOn(@Body requestBody: RequestBody): Call<ResponseBody>
```

`RequestBody` and `ResponseBody` are both `Retrofit` object

```
Call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val decodedString = String(Base64.decode(response.body()!!.string(), Base64.DEFAULT))
            val baseMsType = object : TypeToken<BaseResponse<T>>() {}.type
            val baseMSResponse = Gson().fromJson<BaseResponse<T>>(decodedString, baseMsType)
            listener.success(baseMSResponse)
    }
```

BaseResponse is a generic class

```
class BaseResponse<T>(
    @SerializedName("data") var data: T? = null
)
```

`LogonResponse`

```
data class LogonResponse(
    @SerializedName("token")
    val token: String? = ""
)
```

`listener.success(baseMSResponse)` is custom listener

```
interface ApiCallback<T> {
    fun success(body: BaseResponse<T>)
    fun fail(message: String)
}
```

so far everything works but in ViewModel

```
    private fun logOn(accountInfo: AccountInfo) {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val request = LogonRequest(userID = accountInfo.userID, userName = accountInfo.userName)
            MyService.Account.logOn(request, object : ApiCallback<LogonResponse> {

                override fun success(body: BaseResponse<LogonResponse>) {

                    Log.d("TAG", " logOn success=" + body.data!!.token)//crash in this line
                }

                override fun fail(message: String) {
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.api.response.LogonResponse
[image]

but if i change the code

```
override fun success(body: BaseResponse<LogonResponse>) {

    val response = Gson().fromJson(body.data.toString(), LogonResponse::class.java)
    Log.d("Huang", "  token=" + response.token)//get token success
}
```

why do I need to parse Json again even I have declared type in `ApiCallback`

Comment: what happens if you: rename `LogonResponse` to `LogonResponseData` and  declare a `typealias LogonResponse = BaseResponse<LogonResponseData>` and use that `LogonResponse` instead of `BaseResponse<T>` in gson deserialization?

Comment: @CarloMoretti Thanks for your suggests, but it is still the same result.